What is the better way to create multiple user types in Django? abstract classes or proxy models?
I want to create multiple user types in Django. The user types are 'Admin', 'Company' and 'Individual'. Should I use abstract models or proxy models for this requirement.
I have already done this using proxy models. How would it be done using abstract models instead? Is any one of them better than the other? If so, how?
Here is how I have implemented it using proxy models.
models.py:
class User(AbstractBaseUser, PermissionsMixin):
    id = models.AutoField(primary_key=True)
    email = models.EmailField(max_length=150, unique=True, null=False, blank=False)
    role = models.CharField(max_length=50, choices=Role.choices, null=False, blank=True)
    is_staff = models.BooleanField(null=False, default=False)
    is_active = models.BooleanField(null=False, default=True)
    is_superuser = models.BooleanField(null=False, default=False)

    objects = AccountManager()

    USERNAME_FIELD = "email"

    def __str__(self):
        return self.email

    def has_perm(self, perm, obj=None):
        return self.is_staff

    def has_module_perms(self, app_label):
        return self.is_superuser

class Admin(User):
    objects = AdminManager()

    class Meta:
        proxy = True

    def custom_method_for_admin_only(self):
        return something


class AdminProfile(models.Model):
    admin = models.OneToOneField(
        Admin, on_delete=models.CASCADE, related_name="admin_profile"
    )
    first_name = models.CharField(max_length=50, null=False, blank=False)
    middle_name = models.CharField(max_length=50, null=True, blank=True)
    last_name = models.CharField(max_length=50, null=False, blank=False)

    def __str__(self):
        return f"{self.first_name} {self.last_name}"

class Company(User):
    objects = CompanyManager()

    class Meta:
        proxy = True

    def custom_method_for_company_only(self):
        return something


class CompanyProfile(models.Model):
    company = models.OneToOneField(
        Company, on_delete=models.CASCADE, related_name="company_profile"
    )
    name = models.CharField(max_length=50, null=False, blank=False)
    is_verified = models.BooleanField(default=False, null=False, blank=True)
    logo = models.ImageField(upload_to="images/", null=True, blank=True)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.name

class Individual(User):
    objects = IndividualManager()

    class Meta:
        proxy = True

class IndividualProfile(models.Model):
    individual = models.OneToOneField(
        Individual, on_delete=models.CASCADE, related_name="individual_profile"
    )
    first_name = models.CharField(max_length=50, null=False, blank=False)
    middle_name = models.CharField(max_length=50, null=True, blank=True)
    last_name = models.CharField(max_length=50, null=False, blank=False)

    def __str__(self):
        return f"{self.first_name} {self.last_name}"

And the managers for the models would be something like this:
managers.py:
class Role(models.TextChoices):
    ADMIN = "ADMIN", "Admin"
    COMPANY = "COMPANY", "Company"
    INDIVIDUAL = "INDIVIDUAL", "Individual"

class AccountManager(BaseUserManager):
    def create_superuser(
        self,
        email,
        password,
        first_name=None,
        middle_name=None,
        last_name=None,
        role=Role.ADMIN,
        **other_fields
    ):
        with transaction.atomic():
            other_fields.setdefault("is_staff", True)
            other_fields.setdefault("is_superuser", True)
            other_fields.setdefault("is_active", True)
            if not role == Role.ADMIN:
                raise ValueError("Superuser must have a role of ADMIN.")
            if not email:
                raise ValueError("Superuser must have an email.")
            if not first_name:
                raise ValueError("Superuser must have a first name.")
            if not last_name:
                raise ValueError("Superuser must have a last name.")
            if other_fields.get("is_staff") is not True:
                raise ValueError("Superuser must be assigned to is_staff=True")
            if other_fields.get("is_superuser") is not True:
                raise ValueError("Superuser must be assigned to is_superuser=True")
            email = self.normalize_email(email)
            superuser = self.model(email=email, role=role, **other_fields)
            superuser.set_password(password)
            superuser.save()
            admin_profile_model = apps.get_model("admin_app", "AdminProfile")
            admin_profile_model.objects.create(
                user=superuser,
                first_name=first_name,
                middle_name=middle_name,
                last_name=last_name,
            )
            return superuser

    def create(self, email, password, role=None, **other_fields):
        if not role:
            raise ValueError("A user must have a role.")
        if not email:
            raise ValueError("A user must have an email.")
        email = self.normalize_email(email)
        user = self.model(email=email, role=role, **other_fields)
        user.set_password(password)
        user.save()
        return user

class AdminManager(AccountManager):
    def create(
        self, email, password, first_name, last_name, middle_name=None, **other_fields
    ):
        admin_profile_model = apps.get_model("admin_app", "AdminProfile")
        with transaction.atomic():
            admin = super().create(
                email=email, role=Role.ADMIN, password=password, **other_fields
            )
            admin_profile_model.objects.create(
                admin=admin,
                first_name=first_name,
                middle_name=middle_name,
                last_name=last_name,
            )
            return admin

    def get_queryset(self, *args, **kwargs):
        return super().get_queryset(*args, **kwargs).filter(role=Role.ADMIN)

class CompanyManager(AccountManager):
    def create(self, email, password, name, **other_fields):
        with transaction.atomic():
            company_profile_model = apps.get_model("company", "CompanyProfile")
            company = super().create(
                email=email, role=Role.COMPANY, password=password, **other_fields
            )
            company_profile_model.objects.create(company=company, name=name)
            return company

    def get_queryset(self, *args, **kwargs):
        return super().get_queryset(*args, **kwargs).filter(role=Role.COMPANY)

class IndividualManager(AccountManager):
    def create(
        self, email, password, first_name, last_name, middle_name=None, **other_fields
    ):
        individual_profile_model = apps.get_model("account", "IndividualProfile")
        with transaction.atomic():
            user = super().create(
                email=email, role=Role.INDIVIDUAL, password=password, **other_fields
            )
            individual_profile_model.objects.create(
                user=user,
                first_name=first_name,
                middle_name=middle_name,
                last_name=last_name,
            )
            return user

    def get_queryset(self, *args, **kwargs):
        return super().get_queryset(*args, **kwargs).filter(role=Role.INDIVIDUAL)


Please don't use abstract base models: how will you authenticate these? It would require first looking for the Individual model, then the Admin model, and finally CompanyUser model. If you assign items to users, it will result in three ForeignKeys, etc.

Questions of the form "What is the better way" are usually opinion based and off-topic for this site. Also you seem to be asking multiple questions (What is the better way, How would it be done using abstract models, etc.), one post should only have one question. Please [edit] your post to ask a single objective question.

In fact IMO the most suitable question you could have asked here was "How do I implement multiple user types in Django?" but that would have been a duplicate.


I have already done this using proxy models. How would it be done using abstract models instead? Is any one of them better than the other? If so, how?

Please don't. It will make things a lot more complicated. If a user wants to authenticate, you will have to look through three tables. The AuthenticationMiddleware [Django-doc] that thus assigns request.user based on the session id, will also complicate matters.
A typical use case is that objects refer to the user that is the "owner" of an item, so such ForeignKeys now will have to refer to three possible models resulting in either three ForeignKeys [Django-doc], a GenericForeignKey [Django-doc], or some complicated logic that first has to decypher which of the three.
I think probably the most lean way is to make three possible users with extra data is to work with concrete model inheritance:
class IndividualProfile(User):
    dob = models.DateField(null=True)
and then we can determine Users that are individuals with:
User.objects.filter(individualprofile__isnull=False)

So, all your user types are actually users. So it makes sense to have them as User and you will need to handle their differences. I would suggest it would make sense to store their type and create an abstract model for UserType or something of the like, handling everything all your types should handle similarly inside this abstract model and extend this abstract model with concrete models of your actual types to handle their differences.
